# $_COOKIE does not fetch updated cookie value

Tags: php, cookies

Consider the following code snippet-

```
    if(some_condition){
        echo $candidate_id= $row_id['id'];
        setcookie("candidate_id", $candidate_id, time()+3600);
        echo "<script>console.log(document.cookie)</script>";
    }
    if(isset($_COOKIE['candidate_id'])){
        echo "from cookie";
        echo $candidate_id= $_COOKIE['candidate_id'];exit;  
    }
    else{
        echo "not from cookie";
        echo $candidate_id= $row_id['id'];exit;
    }
```

First time it gives a correct output-

```
 288not from cookie288
```

and in console,

```
candidate_id=288; PHPSESSID=kfpjvl9j4rluh1stjdjcijgi75
```

But if i again run the code again,i get the following outputs

```
289from cookie288
```

and in console,

```
candidate_id=289; PHPSESSID=kfpjvl9j4rluh1stjdjcijgi75
```

This means,on the second run,the cookie value is being modified but `$_COOKIE['candidate_id']` is not fetching the updated value. But why?

Comment: unsetting the cookie before setcookie would defeat the whole purpose of setting a cookie here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_COOKIE` is initialized based on the cookies in the user's request.  It is not updated by calls to `setcookie()`.

You *could* fake it by doing something like this:

```
function mySetCookie($name, $value, $time) {
    setcookie($name, $value, $time);
    $_COOKIE[$name] = $value;
}
```

Then call mySetCookie() wherever you would have called setcookie().  This is possibly buggy, though -- I haven't tested it and am fairly certain it would run into problems in some configurations.